# Oracle SQL ROWNUM < 10 VS MySQL LIMIT 10 performance on huge view

Tags: mysql, oracle, view, query-performance, sql-view

I am trying to query an Oracle SQL view set by a client to get a few sample records.

This view is so huge that SQL Developer gets hung up when I click on its name on the views list to try to display its records.

Client says I should put a where clause to limit the number of records.

The thing is I don't even know what to put in this where clause to get just a few sample records.

In MySQL I would just do `SELECT * FROM huge_view LIMIT 10` (why it works is explained here: http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)

The Oracle equivalent `SELECT * FROM huge_view WHERE ROWNUM < 10` does not work like that, so the query still hungs up and no results.

Is there any way I can get a few random samples from this view without knowing anything about it?

Comment: `ROWCOUNT` or `ROWNUM`?

Comment: yeah, `ROWNUM`, sorry ^^'

Comment: It this was a table you could use `SELECT * FROM huge_table sample(10);`. But I still think you're doing something wrong, such a simple query (without sort) should return instantly.

Comment: Aaa I've got it. It is a view. The view the joins tables and Oracle decided to use hash join. You should use optimizer goal FIRST_ROWS (use hint `/*+ FIRST_ROWS(100) */`) to get result instantly. Oracle should prefer nested loops before hash tables.

Comment: I asked the DBA client why it didn't work. He told me something like "the view is doing a very convoluted query and you should limit the number of records. Just put a where clause." I confirmed I could get a record using `SELECT * FROM huge_view WHERE reference='anitemreference'`. The problem is I don't know which item references are on this view so I tried the `ROWNUM < 10` thing, and also `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`. What I didn't try was `WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 and 10`, I am about to do it now.

Comment: @ibre5041 You are right  `SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10)*/ * FROM huge_view WHERE ROWNUM < 10;` did the trick.